# Accessing elements with IDs via their global variables

Tags: javascript, html, dom, global-variables

It is a not-so-widely-known fact that most* web browsers create a global variable for every element on a page with an `id` attribute:

HTML:

```
<header id="page-header"></header>
```

JS:

```
window['page-header'].style.fontFamily = "Comic Sans MS";
```

My Questions:

- Is this a reliable way to select elements?
- Any reason to use `document.getElementByID` instead? I would guess that accessing ID'd elements with their global variables would be faster than `document.getElementByID`.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/eponug/1/quiet) is a demo.

*I've tested this in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: Please don't downvote just because this is bad practice. I'm asking *why* it's bad practice.

Comment: Found an informative duplicate. Sorry for the bother: [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

Answer (score 2):

I tested it on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/global-dom-id-vs-getelementbyid) and with Chromium v25 getElementByID was much faster

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

If the `window` object already has a property with that name it won't be overwritten.

Elements like `img` that use the `name` attribute will also become properties of the window object. Since the name attribute is not required to be unique, this could happen:

```
<img name="test"/>
<img name="test"/>
<img id="test"/>
```

In some older browsers `window.test` will return a NodeList containing the three elements.

So it is safer to use the `getElementById` method.